# How do I identify the content management system used by a website?

Tags: websites, cms

If I go to a random blog or informational website say, having pages with information, a sidebar with an overview of the archives. I know that this website is built with a CMS. How can I get to know which CMS was used?

So I'm looking for basic, general typicals of common CMSs, so that we can get to know the working power behind any informational website or blog.

For example, a typical might be that WordPress adds such a line to the HTML:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.1" />
```

Comment: This is a question for IT Security site, not for Reverse Engineering.

Comment: This question is on-topic as per the discussion [here](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47/typicals-of-cmss-off-topic)

Answer (score 7):

Install [Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/download) for Chrome or Firefox. If you want to know how it works, the [source code is available](https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for the typicals, not for a program. So could you include the/some typicals in your answer?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "typicals" ?

Comment: _Technical_ stuff, like the one example I mentioned. So you can get that from the source code, but without some code here this is link-only... :(

Comment: @CamilStaps Looks like [this part](https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/blob/master/drivers/chrome/apps.json) of the source code should help. I've also never heard the word "typicals" used as you're using it. I think people will often say "indicator" or "identifier" instead.

Comment: @CamilStaps - Please see amccormack's comment above. The source code containing the identifiers is 2,600 lines long. You will need to click the link to find the information that you are looking for.